# How to write a route that targets an action from a path paramater

Tags: node.js, sails.js

If I have multiple urls like '/some/url/path/foo/bar1', '/some/url/path/foo/bar2', '/some/url/path/foo/bar3' etc. How can I write a single route that will direct the urls to the foo controller and the action of bar1, bar2, bar3 etc.

EG. (only this doesn't work.)

'/some/url/path/foo/:bar' : 'foo.:bar'

Comment: What do you mean by action?

Comment: A controller action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ways to do this. I might suggest that you don't need the different actions in your controller, but just have different cases in a single action that respond to a url param (ex `bar`). That would be more inline with conventions.

However, you can accomplish what you want with the following.

Create your route

```
'/some/url/path/foo/:action': {
     controller: 'FooController',
     action: 'getAction'
}
```

Then in that controller create a `getAction` method. This method can now use `req.param.action` variable to find an execute the corresponding action.

```
FooController.getAction = function(req,res,next){

    return sails.controllers.foo[req.param.action](req,res,next)

}
```

Comment: My question wasn't specific enough. The url path actually has some extra parts to it that are not reflected in the controller folder structure. (See my edited question.) Is it still possible like this?